# Issue with inherited tables within Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an issue in entity framework 4.1 which I seem to be going around in circles with. I am trying to create a simple domain where I have a Case table which has a 1..M relationship with the Question table. I then have an inherited table ('Inherited Question') which shares the Id from the Question table.

What I would like to do is associate the Question and InheritedQuestion classes with the case they are linked to so I could do something like:

```
var inheritedCase = context.Set<Case<InheritedQuestion>>.First();
InheritedQuestion inheritedQuestion = inheritedCase.Case.Questions.First();
```

Is this at all possible? I believe EF has restrictions around generics. I am wondering whether I could get around this via manually mapping class properties?

At the moment I can't work out anyway of implementing this via EF. I have included the basis of my issue below. I have been trying to implement this via the fluent api.

**Case Table**
Id (PK)

**Question Table**
CaseId (FK)
QuestionId (PK)
Field1

Inherited Question
QuestionId (FK)
Field2

These are my classes.

```
public class Case<T> where T : Question
{
  ICollection<T> Questions {get;set;}
}

public class Question
{
  string Field1 {get;set;}
  Case<Question> Case {get;set;}
}

public class InheritedQuestion : Question
{
  string Field2 {get;set;}
  new Case<InheritedQuestion> Case {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: EF doesn't understand/like the `new` modifier here. Rename the 2nd Case.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Not quite, but close. If `InheritedQuestion` is a `Question`, then it has a property with type `Case<Question>`. There's no way around that, as long as `Question` has that property and `InheritedQuestion` inherits from it. But the way `InheritedQuestion` is written now, it has two completely separate properties `Case`, which is (as far as I can guess) not the intended behaviour. This needs to be fixed at the C# level before it can be made suitable for EF.

Comment: That said, as I recall, EF doesn't support custom generic types at all, so I don't think this is going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. You must use this:

```
public class Case
{
  ICollection<Question> Questions {get;set;}
}

public class Question
{
  string Field1 {get;set;}
  Case Case {get;set;}
}

public class InheritedQuestion : Question
{
  string Field2 {get;set;}
}
```

Now your Case should be able to associate with both questions and Inherited questions.

If you need only single type of questions in case create either two case types or add custom logic to your application which will validate that case contains only single question type.

To support multiple case types you can try this:

```
// Not mapped class!
public abstract BaseCase<T> where T : question
{
    ICollection<T> Questions { get; set; }
}

// Mapped entities
public Case : BaseCase<Question> { }
public Case2 : BaseCase<InheritedQuestion> { }
```